# Conditional insert into table in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have 2 tables TABLE_A and TABLE_B. When there is no row in TABLE_B I want to insert a dummy row in TABLE_A and if there is any row in TABLE_B I want to insert whatever is present into TABLE_A. How can we do this ?

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A(
    id          STRING      NOT NULL
  , uid         STRING      NOT NULL
  , date        STRING      NOT NULL
  , timestamp   TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL
  , payload     OBJECT      NOT NULL
  , arr         ARRAY       NOT NULL
)
;

CREATE TABLE TABLE_B(
    id          STRING      NOT NULL
  , uid         STRING      NOT NULL
  , date        STRING      NOT NULL
  , timestamp   TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL
  , payload     OBJECT      NOT NULL
  , arr         ARRAY       NOT NULL
)
;
```

When COUNT(*) = 0 in TABLE_B Then
Insert 'dummy_id','dummy_uid', current_date(), current_timestamp(), TO_OBJECT(PARSE_JSON('{}')), TO_ARRAY('DUMMY_ROWS')
into TABLE_A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
  SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    'dummy_id','dummy_uid', current_date(), current_timestamp(),
    TO_OBJECT(PARSE_JSON('{}')), TO_ARRAY('DUMMY_ROWS') 
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_B) = 0
```

Only one part of UNION ALL will contain something.

Btw, this solution should in general work for any DBMS, not only Snowflake.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **CASE function of SQL** , you can write something like that

```
INSERT into table_A(),
CASE
WHEN (select count(*) from table_b ) > 0 
THEN select * from table_b
ELSE "some dummy data"
END
FROM table_b;
```

This is not the copy paste answer but from this you can find your path

Comment: this is not going to work. I have tried all approaches as mentioned in https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/insert-multi-table.html

Comment: This is not even close to valid SQL